# Outputting query variables

Tags: database, bash, db2

I have this:

```
db2 -x "SELECT title, description FROM pages" | while read title description ; do
    echo "$title $description";
done
```

However, when it echos, it outputs like this:

```
Hello World                                        Description
Another Title                                      Description
Title Description
```

As you can see, if the title has 2 words, it prints the description off to the side, while if the title is 1 word, it prints the description right next to the title.

How can I output the results in a formatted and organized manner?

Answer (score 0):

```
db2 -x 'SELECT title, description FROM pages' |
awk '{printf "%-13s  %s\n", $1, $2}' FS=' {2,}'
```

Result

```
Hello World    Description
Another Title  Description
Title          Description
```

Comment: Using `awk` here is unnecessary - bash has its own `printf`.

Comment: Sure: `echo title description | while read t d ; do printf "%-13s  %s\n" $t $d ; done`. The setting of `$IFS` can be modified to deal with whatever delimiter `db2 -x` uses (I don't know what that is, sorry).

Answer (score 0):

you can use '-e' option for echo like this :

```
db2 -x "SELECT title, description FROM pages" | while read title description ; do
    echo -e "$title \t $description";
done

Hello World            Description
Another Title          Description
Title                  Description


-e     enable interpretation of backslash escapes

\t     horizontal tab
```

for more information [Man Page echo](http://www.unix.com/man-page/linux/0/echo/)

Comment: This does not work, it just adds a tab to the situation, but the columns will not line up.

Comment: This doesn't work. If `title` has two words, it prints it out with a tab between the words as well, as in: `Another \t Title \t Description`